# Angular directives - How to select template based on attribute values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

I am developing a widget where I want to render some messages/text one after another. I want to change the template of the message based on the type of message.

my current directive setup is as follows

```
directive('cusMsgText', function(){
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     template:function(elements, attrs){
        return '<div></div>';
     },
     link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
        //add children to iElm based on msg values in $scope
     }
  };
});
```

The directive is used as follows

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in chatUser.msg">  
    <data-cus-msg-text msg="value.type"></data-cus-msg-text>  
</div>
```

Now my question are -:

1. Is it possible to return one of multiple strings (templates) from
   template function itself based on the actual value of attribute
   `msg`.   I tried accessing `attrs.msg` in template function and it
   return `value.type`.
2. If not then, Is it good to manipulate template under `linker` or I
   need to move it to `compile` function?

Answer (score 7):

To render a different template based on `value.type` you can use the `ng-switch` statement:

```
<div ng-switch="value.type">
    <div ng-switch-when="type1">
        //...template for type 1 here...
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="type2">
        //...template for type 2 here...
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, if I understood your second question: manipulation of the uncompiled directive should be done in the `compile` function, all the manipulation which occurs after compilation should go in the `link` function.

[Docs for ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

**EDIT**: +1 to Sebastian for understanding what you wanted. However, what he is proposing is essentially reinventing the wheel, since it is essentially compiling and inserting the template manually (which is what `ngSwitch` does for you). Also, you can access the attributes you put on your directive through the `attrs` argument of the `link` function.

Comment: I am not able to access actual value provide in attributes of directives. under template function value.type is a string.

Comment: In the example you provide, your directive has a `msg` attribute. If I understand, you pass the type to the directive through that attribute. You can `switch` on that value, I don't see the problem. Moreover, what do you mean by "template function"? `Link` function?

Answer (score 4):

In the `template` function you don't have access to the `scope` of your directive. If you want to control what gets rendered you can do this using conditional logic (e.g. `ng-switch`) in a global template as suggested by simoned or use a `link` function:

```
.directive('cusMsgText', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      msg: '=',
      item: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      templates = {
        x: '<div>template x {{item.name}}</div>',
        y: '<div>template y {{item.name}}</div>'
      };

      var html = templates[scope.msg];
      element.replaceWith($compile(html)(scope));
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to parse the attribute values in template function? +1.